# Not able to access a button inside a listbox in the code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, datatemplate

I am having a textbox and button inside a Listbox in a WPF application. Now, I have a scenario like, when I click on the button the text block needs to be in edit mode and the button needs to be in a hidden state. Once the user is done with the edit(a keyup event is called on the textbox), the button needs to be in a visible mode.
I am calling a click event on the button and make it hidden, now I have to access the textbox inside the click event function to make it in editable mode(read-only false). In the same way, when I am done with the editing I need to call the button inside the Keyup event handler of the text box to make the button visible. But I am not getting the controls in the code behind.
I knew the DataTemplate binding of the list view causing this issue. So to make the button visible, I did the following code and it is working.

```
private void controlEdit_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var edtBtn = sender as Button;
        if (edtBtn != null)
        {
            edtBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }

    }
```

But I dont know how to call this button inside my text box Keyup event handler, the same way the text box inside this button click event handler. My list box XAML and the KeyUp event handler are adding.

XAML

```
 <ListBox x:Name="ElList" Height="auto" Width="300" Background="Transparent" DataContext="{Binding collec}" ItemsSource="{Binding collec}"  Grid.Row="0" Margin="31 3" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                                    <TextBox x:Name="controltext" Width="153.7" Height="24.4" BorderBrush="#ffffff" FontFamily= "{StaticResource MontserratMedium}"  Padding="2 0 0 0 " Text="{Binding ElName, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="False" KeyDown="controltext_KeyDown" KeyUp="controltext_KeyUp" LostKeyboardFocus="controltext_LostKeyboardFocus"/>
                                    <Button x:Name="controlEdit" Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}" Margin="3 0 0 0 " Click="controlEdit_Click_1">
                                        <Image x:Name="featherImg"  Source="Resources\feather_edit-3.png"  Height="11" Width="11"/>
                                    </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

TextBox KeyUp event handler

```
 private void controltext_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        string NewName = ((System.Windows.Controls.TextBox)sender).Text;
        //Make the button visble.
    }
```

So suggest me a way how to access the text box inside the button click event handler and the same way the button inside text box KeyUp.

Answer (score 1):

if you know the structure of visual tree, it is possible to navigate it using Parent and Children properties:

```
private void controltext_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  var textbox = (TextBox)sender;
  var panel = (StackPanel)textbox.Parent;
  var button = panel.Children.OfType<Button>().FirstOrDefault(b => b.Name == "controlEdit");
}
```

Children property is meanaingful for Panels, Controls have Content, Decorators (like Border) have Child property